# Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' Syncronous

Tags: javascript, http

I'm trying to connect to google with a simple get request through JS and it seems to always be giving me the same error.

"Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://google.com'."

Any clue why this would be happening? Relevant code is below.

```
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://google.com", false);
        try {
            xmlHttp.send();
        } catch (err) {
            alert("EXCEPTION: " + err.message);
        }
        alert("here's the result of the get: " + xmlHttp.responseText);
```

Comment: Try with "www", I mean `http://www.google.com`

Comment: If you run the request asynchronously and look in your console, you'll see a much more helpful error message: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Fiddler is your friend.  Does it even make a request to the remote server?

Comment: @Zuzlx The browser probably *does* make the HTTP request (otherwise, how would it determine if the response contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?). I don't think examining the HTTP request will be helpful here.

Comment: @SudeepJuvekar Your fiddle fetches the resource `https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/www.google.com`, rather than `http://www.google.com`

Comment: @apsillers 10-4 on that.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a cross-origin permission failure, due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). If you ran this same request asynchronously and looked in your console, you'd see the much more helpful error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://[whatever]' is therefore not allowed access.

This is because only scripts run on pages from `http://www.google.com` may read resources from `http://www.google.com`. If the resource being fetched served appropriate CORS headers (e.g., `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`), you would not see this error. (However, `http://www.google.com` serves no such headers).