# NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'Sub.domain.com' - call web api using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, dns, cross-domain

I have developed web application using Web API 2 and MCV 5.
I am try to call web api using javascript and getting NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'Sub.domain.com' to the colsole.

```
var param = {
    "EmailID": email,
};

var appUrl = '@ConfigHelper.ApiURL';
var url = appUrl + 'user/checkemailid';

//create xml http request for request api url
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (json) {
        debugger;
        if (json.IsSuccessful) {
            swal("", "Email id already exist.", "warning");                  
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        debugger;
        swal('', data.Message, 'error');
    }
});
```

and also add cross origin for both project web and api. 
write following code into web.config

```
 <system.webServer>

    <!-- Cross origin for Domain-->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

and follwing code into global.aspx file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Let me know where I'm missing anything.

i am trying to implement many solution like 
[Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' Syncronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729084/failed-to-execute-send-on-xmlhttprequest-syncronous) but not getting luck

Same code snippet is working for this project for other domain but not working from main domain to sub domain api call.

Comment: I spent an hour dealing with the issue, while the problem was in my AdBlocker blocking the requests...

Answer (score 0):

You can add following as well in the $.ajax() parameter object -

```
"crossDomain": true,
"headers": {
              "accept": "application/json",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
          }
```